# Bios settings for Dual Booting Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, thinkpad, bios

I have a thinkpad x1 that has both windows and Ubuntu installed. When I installed Ubuntu I had to make some bios changes but recently I reset my bios settings and now it boots straight into windows, grub doesn't even pop up. Any suggestions for getting grub back?

Comment: UEFI (UEFI is not BIOS) > Boot. Select Ubuntu instead of Windows, that should be all unless you need some other settings changed that the reset obviously changed back to the defaults.

Answer (score -1):

If you have windows 8,8.1,or 10 installed on your laptop, you can boot ubuntu using Windows os.

Check this article below. It will tell you how to do this.

https://winaero.com/tip-boot-windows-10-into-advanced-startup-options-quickly/

https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/ko-kr/000147155/booting-to-the-advanced-startup-options-menu-in-windows-10?lang=en

So when you enter **Advanced Startup** option , there is a option called " use another operating system".
All you need is just choose it and boot your linux distro.

Read this >>
https://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

If this does not help, try to install **grub4win**.

Answer (score -1):

GRUB is typically installed wherever Ubuntu is located.  You need to access your BIOS settings and point your BIOS to boot from the volume where Ubuntu is installed.  Right now it is probably choosing the Windows volume first.

BIOS is your motherboard firmware (hardware-level) and not associated with any operating system.

Every motherboard is different and the process is not consistent between motherboards and sometimes not even the same with different motherboards from the same manufacturer.

If you cannot determine the correct setting by looking, you will have to research the documentation for your motherboard to determine how to do this.